# Why won't a Android 1.5 app run on Android 2.2 phone or emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an Android application using Android 1.5. I'm using an older version of the SDK because I'm building it to run on a single G1 phone.

I've been using a 2.1 emulator without any problems, but when I tried taking a look on my Nexus One (2.2), the application immediately stopped responding. I then tried a 2.2 emulator with the same result.

Has anyone seen a similar problem or know of a possible solution?

The project isn't very complicated. I have a service running in the background that listens to incoming text messages and passes those messages on to a database. When I run the program in debug mode, it never hits a breakpoint on the first line of the first activity. It is as if it cannot even load.

Comment: Have you checked the logcat output for an exception?  They have moved a number of classes around between 1.5 and 2.2.  I'd check to see if an exception is being thrown and then post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a solution for this. The above suggestion didn't work. In my specific situation, the app doesn't *have* to run on 2.2, so I'm just avoiding it.

How's that for a solution?? :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi Quenton i had a similar issue

inside my Manifest.xml i had android:name property

```
 < application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="@string/appname">
```

delete android:name property

```
< application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```